# Docker "/bin/bash" could not be invoked when mounting an NFS file with -v on openstack

Tags: networking, docker, openstack, mount, nfs

I'm running an `Ubuntu 14.04` instance that has docker installed on openstack. I'm trying to mount a volume into a docker container. I'm doing this with

```
docker run -t -i -v /mnt/data/dir:/mnt/test ubuntu
```

Where `/mnt/data/dir` is an NFS shared directory. Doing this gets me:

> docker: 
>           Error response from daemon: Container command '/bin/bash' could not be invoked..

However, using a local directory instead of a mounted directory works exactly as expected.

I understand that docker doesn't natively support an NFS mounted file system, however the errors I googled are usually not of the form that I've mentioned above.

Any clue on how to proceed

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that its not just limited to `/bin/bash` could not be invoked. I tried running a tomcat server and that gave me the exact same error.

Comment: Can you access the NFS directory from the docker host? What does your /etc/exports look like on the NFS server?

Comment: Yes I can access the NFS directory from the Host. I dont have access to the NFS server but I've been told its already exported (and I can successfully access it so that can be confirmed.) I have r/w access to the directory.